# How to set a specific value for multiple shape keys?

Tags: edit-mode, shape-keys

I have about 300 shapekeys and want set all of them to value 0.5 or 1. Is there a fast way to do it?

Comment: is it for one object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small script to set them all to a new_value except the basic shapekey :

- select the object
- copy paste and run the script

---

```
import bpy

new_value = 0.5

for shape in bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    if shape.name != 'Basic' :
        shape.value = new_value
```