# How to set a random value for multiple shape keys?

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode, shape-keys

My question is related to my previous asked one: [How to set a specific value for multiple shape keys?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27872/how-to-set-a-specific-value-for-multiple-shape-keys)

I have about 300 shapekeys and want to set a random value for all of them. How to do this via script?

Comment: Frankly, I asked this question to help @Ashwin with his problem. Both scripts work great. You can see them in action here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40381/is-it-possible-to-create-many-random-people-faster-than-creating-each-one-of-the

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend [`random.uniform(a,b)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.uniform) for a random float range:

```
import bpy
import random

obj = bpy.context.object

# test if the object is a mesh and check if shape keys have been added 
if obj.type == 'MESH' and hasattr(obj.data.shape_keys, "key_blocks"):
    
    # iterate through the shape keys of the object
    for shape_key in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
        
        # check if it's not the first one
        if shape_key.name is not 'Basis':
            
            # assign a random float between 0 and 1
            shape_key.value = random.uniform(0, 1)
            
            # print the values
            print (shape_key.value)
```

The values should look like this:

```
0.5418003797531128
0.4634256660938263
0.77964186668396
0.37678709626197815
0.8787218332290649
...
```

---

For *better access*, I've implemented this functionality into [**this Add-on**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40624/3710):

[image]

**Exclude** input field checks whether the 'name' of the shape key starts with 'your input' and also accepts multiple values (*comma seperated*)  in order to ignore *placeholder shape keys* like 
 `--- Test ---` or `### Test ###` via `*, -` at once.

Comment: Thanks @poor! The script works great. BTW You've changed avatar, right? Looks more modern that your previous one ;).

Comment: The script works really great :D!!! Could you please improve it adding the following options: 'randomize shapekeys visibility', 'add/remove drivers to/from visible/all shapekeys', 'apply shapekeys to left/right side of the mesh (as you can do in Blend window in ShapeKeys panel)'. Thanks again!

Comment: Here you are: http://s11.postimg.org/js6bzdm5v/proposal_3_OK.jpg Not much has changed according to the UI you proposed though. One thing I would like to add is a reversed functionallity of the 'exclude' option (fantastic idea BTW :)), which may allow you to add values to only defined shape keys. The options I proposed are everything I need... I guess? ;).

Comment: I've posted a comment 3 days ago on a GitHub with some changes proposal. Have you checked it? Also, here is a simple character basemesh with some shape keys: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=705" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/705/) May be helpful for testing the add-on.

Comment: To have the first script to work for multiple selected objects:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273932/8282

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy
from random import random, uniform

for sk in bpy.data.shape_keys:
    for i, kb in enumerate(sk.key_blocks.values()):
        if not i:
            # assume kb[0] is 'Basis'
            continue
        # set random value
        kb.value = kb.slider_min + random() * (kb.slider_max - kb.slider_min)
        # eqivalent using random.uniform suggested by poor.
        #kb.value = uniform(kb.slider_min, kb.slider_max)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! You're incredible :O. Both scripts work super fine. As the @batFINGER came first with the script, I accept his answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to uncheck the 'accept' button. poor 's solution is the one I wanted. Your solution'll be helpful for my future projects though, so thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

For those who just want to have the [Accepted Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40387/8282) to work for multiple selected objects, do this:

```
import bpy
import random

# iterate through all mesh objects in selection
for obj in [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']:

    # iterate through the shape keys of the current object
    if hasattr(obj.data.shape_keys, "key_blocks"):
        for shape_key in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:

            # check if it's not the first one
            if shape_key.name is not 'Basis':

                # assign a random float between 0 and 1
                shape_key.value = random.uniform(0, 1)

                # print the values
                print (shape_key.value)
```