# How to set a random value for only visible shape keys?

Tags: scripting, edit-mode, shape-keys

My question is related to my previous asked one: [How to set a random value for multiple shape keys?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40382/how-to-set-a-random-value-for-multiple-shape-keys)

I want to set the random values ***for only visible shapekeys***. Is it possible using scripting?
[image]

I would also like to know how to set a specific value (like 0.5) for all visible shape keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy
from random import uniform
context = bpy.context
obj = context.object

def set_shapekeys(obj, value=0.5, random=False):
    sk = obj.data.shape_keys
    for i, kb in enumerate(sk.key_blocks.values()):
        if not i or kb.mute:
            # assume kb[0] is 'Basis'
            continue
        if random:
            kb.value = uniform(kb.slider_min, kb.slider_max)
        else:
            kb.value = value

#set visible keys to random

set_shapekeys(obj, random=True)

#set visible keys to 0.7

#set_shapekeys(obj, value=0.7)
```

Use set_shapekeys(obj, value=0.5) to set all visible shapekeys to 0.5

Comment: WOW! Thank you so very much!!! Scripting is a black magic for me :). Really appreciate your help!