# How to disable/enable multiple shapekeys visibility?

Tags: scripting, edit-mode, shape-keys

I have over 300 shapekeys added to my mesh. How can I disable and enable the visibility for all of them using scripting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate through the shape keys and check the current state of the [`mute`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShapeKey.html?highlight=mute#bpy.types.ShapeKey.mute) attribute. Since it is a simple bool property which only can be `True` or `False`, I'd suggest write a **toggle** in order to enable or disable all shape keys of the selected object per execution:

```
import bpy

# iterate through the shape keys of the active object
for shape_key in bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:

    # toggle (if true set it to false and vice versa)
    shape_key.mute = not shape_key.mute
```

---

Considering your [last question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40382/how-to-set-a-random-value-for-multiple-shape-keys) and especially for a **better workflow**, I'd recommend writing a small Add-on instead of running code in the editor for each step:

[image]

#### shape_key_extras.py (updated for 2.8+)

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

bl_info = {
    "name": "Shape Key Extras",
    "description": "",
    "author": "p2or",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "Properties > Object Data > Shape Keys",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh"
}

import bpy
import random

from bpy.props import (IntProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       PointerProperty)

from bpy.types import (Operator,
                       PropertyGroup)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Helper    
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

def exclude_by_name(char_sequence, name):
    if char_sequence:
        char_list = [i.strip() for i in char_sequence.split(",")]
        if name.startswith(tuple(char_list)):
            return True
        else: 
            return False
    else: 
        return False

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Properties    
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class SKE_PG_settings(PropertyGroup):

    value: FloatProperty(
        name = "Value",
        description = "Set static value",
        default = 0,
        #min = 0,
        #max =1
        )
    random_min: FloatProperty(
        name = "Min",
        description = "Set minimum random value",
        default = 0,
        #min = 0,
        #max =1
        )
    random_max: FloatProperty(
        name = "Max",
        description = "Set maximum random value",
        default = 1,
        #min = 0,
        #max =1
        )
    apply_enabled: BoolProperty (
        name = "Apply Values to enabled Keys only",
        description = "Apply values to enabled Keys only",
        default = True 
        )
    exclude: StringProperty (
        name = "Exclude",
        description = "Exclude by first character",
        default = "#, =, *"
        )

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Operators    
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

class SKE_OT_enableAll(Operator):
    bl_idname = "shapekeyextras.enable_all"
    bl_label = "Enable All"
    bl_description = "Enable all Shape Keys"

    def execute(self, context):       
        for shapekey in context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
            shapekey.mute = False

        self.report({'INFO'}, "All enabled")     
        return {'FINISHED'}


class SKE_OT_disableAll(Operator):
    bl_idname = "shapekeyextras.disable_all"
    bl_label = "Disable All"
    bl_description = "Disable all Shape Keys"

    def execute(self, context):       
        for shapekey in context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
            shapekey.mute = True

        self.report({'INFO'}, "All Shape Keys disabled")        
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SKE_OT_toggleAll(Operator):
    bl_idname = "shapekeyextras.toggle"
    bl_label = "Toggle Mute"
    bl_description = "Toggle Mute of all Shape Keys"

    def execute(self, context):        
        for shapekey in context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
            shapekey.mute = not shapekey.mute

        self.report({'INFO'}, "Enabled Shape Keys disabled and Disabled Shape Keys enabled")          
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SKE_OT_randomizeValues(Operator):
    bl_idname = "shapekeyextras.randomize"
    bl_label = "Randomize Values"
    bl_description = "Randomize all Shape Key Values"

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        ske = scn.shape_key_extras

        if ske.apply_enabled is True:       
            for shapekey in context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
                exclude_char = exclude_by_name(ske.exclude, shapekey.name)
                if shapekey.name is not 'Basis' and exclude_char is not True:
                    if shapekey.mute is False:
                        shapekey.value = random.uniform(ske.random_min, ske.random_max)
        else:
            for shapekey in context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
                exclude_char = exclude_by_name(ske.exclude, shapekey.name)
                if shapekey.name is not 'Basis' and exclude_char is not True:
                    shapekey.value = random.uniform(ske.random_min, ske.random_max)

        self.report({'INFO'}, "Values for Shape Keys generated")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SKE_OT_applyValues(Operator):
    bl_idname = "shapekeyextras.apply"
    bl_label = "Apply Values"
    bl_description = "Apply a static Value to all Shape Keys"

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        ske = scn.shape_key_extras

        if ske.apply_enabled is True:       
            for shapekey in context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
                exclude_char = exclude_by_name(ske.exclude, shapekey.name)
                if shapekey.name is not 'Basis' and exclude_char is not True:              
                    if shapekey.mute is False:
                        shapekey.value = ske.value
        else:
            for shapekey in context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
                exclude_char = exclude_by_name(ske.exclude, shapekey.name)
                if shapekey.name is not 'Basis' and exclude_char is not True:
                    shapekey.value = ske.value

        self.report({'INFO'}, "Value assigned to Shape Keys")        
        return {'FINISHED'}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#   UI    
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

def draw_shapekey_extras(self, context):

    scn = context.scene
    layout = self.layout
    ske = scn.shape_key_extras

    layout.separator()
    layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.
    layout.use_property_split = False
    
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Mute State")
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    rowsub = col.row(align=True)
    rowsub.operator(SKE_OT_enableAll.bl_idname, icon="RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF")
    rowsub.operator(SKE_OT_disableAll.bl_idname, icon="RESTRICT_VIEW_ON")
    col.operator(SKE_OT_toggleAll.bl_idname, icon="FILE_REFRESH")
    
    layout.separator()
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Set Shape Key Values")
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    rowsub = col.row(align=True)
    rowsub.prop(ske, "random_min")
    rowsub.prop(ske, "random_max")
    col.operator(SKE_OT_randomizeValues.bl_idname)
    
    row = layout.row()
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    col.prop(ske, "value")
    col.operator(SKE_OT_applyValues.bl_idname)
    
    row = layout.row()
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    col.prop(ske, "exclude")
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    col.prop(ske, "apply_enabled")
    layout.separator()


# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# register    
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    SKE_PG_settings,
    SKE_OT_enableAll,
    SKE_OT_disableAll,
    SKE_OT_toggleAll,
    SKE_OT_randomizeValues,
    SKE_OT_applyValues,
)


def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_shape_keys.append(draw_shapekey_extras)
    bpy.types.Scene.shape_key_extras = PointerProperty(type=SKE_PG_settings)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_shape_keys.remove(draw_shapekey_extras)
    del bpy.types.Scene.shape_key_extras


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: WOW WOW WOW!!! :O. @poor I can't believe my eyes! I am super grateful :D. If I only could give you some of my reputation to thank you. BTW Maybe you should think about selling this add-on on Blender Market. I'll be the first person to buy it and repay you for your effort. You've made my day. Can't wait to test it out :).

Answer (score 5):

```
import bpy

for key_block in bpy.context.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    key_block.mute = True
```