# Giving Shapekeys a random starting value?

Tags: python, drivers, shape-keys

I *love* the "random" input in the shader editor; it makes it so easy to randomize duplicated objects by changing the color and offsetting textures and all that. It would be crazy useful to be able to do a similar thing with shapekeys, so the geometry can vary as well.

I can control the value with a driver, and I tried the method in [this fantastic video](https://vimeo.com/40389198), but that changes the shapekey value on every frame (as happens with every "random" solution I've tried so far), which means in an animation it's a jittery mess (he suggests "muting" the drivers to fix this, but the scene still runs super slowly, since I think it's still running the randomizer for every value for every frame, even if you can't see it).

So my question is, how can I give that shapekey a random static value? I figure something like multiplying the object's ID by a wacky number or something, but I just can't figure it out.

I feel embarrassed posting this, because I feel like this is a fairly basic thing that's probably answered elsewhere, but I've been searching obsessively for a couple days and just keep finding the same few threads over and over, so hopefully someone here knows?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. If the linked post does not answer your question, just let us know. The add-on mentioned in the answer has been updated recently too and should work perfectly: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40621/how-to-disable-enable-multiple-shapekeys-visibility/40624#40624. BTW: recommend take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, cheers.